# Updating an iOS app and having the SQLite3 tables not be replaced

Tags: iphone, ios, sqlite

I have an iPhone app, and it has a database in it that gets updated when the user does some stuff in the app. I'm concerned that when I push an update, it will push the empty database too, getting rid of all their data. How can I tell Apple to not replace the database? How can I keep all the user's settings and information that they will not want to lose in the app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you update data in the DB, you must already be copying it from the Resources folder to the Documents folder. Otherwise, your codesigned app would refuse to launch after the first time it inserts/updates data in the database.

Thus, all you have to do is make sure your own application doesn't overwrite the existing database. When you update an app, the Documents folder stays untouched so from the app's perspective it doesn't know if it was just launched for the very first time, a second time or just updated.

Comment: so you're saying as long as I don't manually (in my application) overwrite the database, it should remain the way it was? wohooo, that's great news.

Comment: The position in the bundle doesn't matter. What matters is where you copy your database on the device. The only choices (programmatically) are the Documents or the Temporary folder. If you don't copy your database and still insert data, your app would currently stop working the first time a user updates some data in it.

Comment: so you're saying that if my app works for users (which it does...it's in the app store), then my database will not be replaced when the app is updated. is this correct?

Comment: If your app works, is on the App Store and you don't get user complaints then either you, a framework you use or one of your developers must have written code to copy the app from the bundle. As your app doesn't know if it was just updated or just relaunched, the fact that your data isn't lost between launches means that the DB is not replaced. So yes, an update will not replace your database.